# Probability distribution of a system of atoms

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

In a system with $N$ independent atoms each with magnetic moment $\mu$ directed either parallel or antiparallel to an external zero magnetic field; that is, $H = 0$. What is the probability distribution?

Okay, so I know that each of the independent atoms has $2$ possible states for its magnetic moment, so there are $2^{N}$ possible states of the total magnetic moment. I don't understand how to find the probability distribution function from here; perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question.

I know that the thermodynamic limit is when $N$ and $V$ approach infinity with  $N/V$ constant, but I'm not so sure about the magnetization

Comment: $M$ is the magnetization, or the magnetic moment per unit volume. It is analagous to density. If you look at a larger volume, you will also be looking at "more magnetic moment", just like how if you look a larger volume of "stuff" with some density, you will also be looking at more mass. Also you never really say what you are trying to find the probability distribution of. Having it of "this arrangement" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you mean magnetic moment directions? Like the probability of observing a moment in a certain direction? Arrangements is somewhat of an ambiguous term.

Comment: There are $2^N$ individual moment configurations, but there are not that many different states with a certain total moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $2^N$ configurations for the system if you are counting each individual moment. There are not this many possibilities for total magnetic moment.

For example, for considering total number of parallel moments, there are $n_p=N+1$ possibilities from $0$ to $N$. Therefore, there is also this many possibilities for the total moment, which can be determined by $\mu_t=\mu(n_p-n_a)=\mu(n_p-(N-n_p))=\mu(2n_p-N)$ where $n_a$ is the number of antiparallel moments.

Now to figure out the number of ways to get each total, you can use combinatorics (like $N$ choose $n_p$), for some choice of $n_p$.

From here you can determine the probability of finding the system with some net magnetic moment. Note that even though each $2^N$ configuration is equally likely, each total moment is not equally likely. Since this seems like a homework problem, I will leave the details to you.

Comment: There is [already a chat for discussions on this answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83149/discussion-between-stackofhay42-and-aaron-stevens). Please carry on the conversation there, not in the comments here.

Answer (score -2):

A probability distribution over microstates is not a physical thing, rather it represents a measure over the set of possible microstates consistent with the observed macrostate. In addition, in classical thermodynamics, we want the distribution to be consistent with thermodynamic equilibrium. That is, the distribution should not change over time, if the system is in contact with a heat bath.

Without any further information, then, it is impossible to pick the 'right' distribution in your case, because you haven't specified what form the system's energy takes, and if the system is in contact with a heat bath, and if it is, what is the temperature of the heat bath.

If you do those things, then you can define a probability distribution, which will be something of the form of $Z \exp(-\beta E)$, which is the Gibbs measure.

Comment: On the contrary, not every microstate is equally probable, as the Gibbs measure shows. Microstates with higher energy are less probable than those with lower energy.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information as to what kind of model you are considering and what the macrostate observables are.

Comment: @stackofhay42 not all probabilities are the same in the normal distribution. Perhaps you mean uniform distribution?